# How to disable SCSS Vendor url import?

Tags: webpack, sass

Using Webpack in the project for compiling modules. One of them (Bootswatch) overrides a lot of Bootstrap to apply a theme.

Right at the beginning of the `_bootswatch.scss` it has:

```
$web-font-path: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic" !default;
@import url($web-font-path);
```

This import is always run, resulting in a request that need not happen (as the font is overriden to "Segoe UI" or something, which is usually installed and does not need to be downloaded.

**How can I ensure the `url($...)` never gets done?**

I've tried setting it to `false`, `''` and `""` and tried searching for it, but keep getting things about changing it instead of disabling it. Also did not find how to disable it [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url())

These changes were done like so:

```
@import "~bootswatch/dist/darkly/variables";

$web-font-path: '' !important;
```

The changes all result in variations on:

```
 WAIT  Compiling...                                                                                                                                                                                                                            2:24:33 PM

 WARNING  Compiled with 1 warnings                                                                                                                                                                                                             2:24:35 PM

 warning  in ./assets/css/admin/admin.scss

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(1:1) Unable to find uri in '@import url("" !important)' // insert other tried values here
```

It's the following request I want to get rid off:

[image: some requests]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to accomplish the exact same thing.

This answer helped me:
[Bootstrap CSS without Google Fonts 2 (Bootswatch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772357/bootstrap-css-without-google-fonts-2-bootswatch)

Specifically, I used double-quotes without !important, and set it before my imports:

```
$web-font-path: "";
@import "~bootswatch/dist/darkly/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```